# How do I customize the bash prompt on centos?

Tags: bash, prompt

I've altered the `/etc/bashrc` file.

I commented out the previous definition and inserted my own:

```
PS1="--bash: (\u@\h:\w) $"
```

This is not having any affect.  When I make this change at the command prompt, it works great, but then it's not permanent.

Answer (score 9):

`/etc/bashrc` is the system setting. The usual place to change the prompt would be the per-user file, `~/.bashrc`. You might already have a setting there that's overwriting the system default. Put your prompt string in `~/.bashrc`.

Furthermore, there is a quirk in bash's handling of initialization files. The `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` files are only read for interactive instances of bash that are not login shell. If you run a login shell, bash only reads `/etc/profile`, and `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile` if it doesn't exist). You need to explicitly source your `.bashrc` from your `.bash_profile` if the login shell is interactive:

```
# Work around a well-known bash design bug: bash does not read .bashrc if
# it is invoked as a login shell.
case "$-" in *i*) if test -r ~/.bashrc; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac
```

Comment: This can go as a comment in your question, or in this answer.  As such, I'm posting in the correct answer that needs more info.  If you're looking at customizing your prompt after following Giles Answer, see [Gentoo: Prompt Magic](https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/prompt-magic.xml)

Comment: @eyeoung100 - This link is no longer valid